# Update post meta without deleting the old entries

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

```
$old = get_post_meta($post_id, 'figure_sugsubject_repeatable_fields', true);
$new = array();

$figuresugsubjectpositions = $_POST['figuresugsubjectposition'];
$figuresugsubjectworkplaces = $_POST['figuresugsubjectworkplace'];
$figuresugsubjectlocations = $_POST['figuresugsubjectlocation'];
$figuresugsubjectfroms = $_POST['figuresugsubjectfrom'];
$figuresugsubjectstatuss = $_POST['figuresugsubjectstatus'];


$count = count( $figuresugsubjectpositions );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
if ( $figuresugsubjectpositions[$i] != '' ) :
    $new[$i]['figuresugsubjectposition'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $figuresugsubjectpositions[$i] ) );

    $new[$i]['figuresugsubjectworkplace'] = $figuresugsubjectworkplaces[$i];
    $new[$i]['figuresugsubjectlocation'] = $figuresugsubjectlocations[$i];
    $new[$i]['figuresugsubjectfrom'] = $figuresugsubjectfroms[$i];
    $new[$i]['figuresugsubjectstatus'] = $figuresugsubjectstatuss[$i];

endif;
}

if ( !empty( $new ) && $new != $old )
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'figure_sugsubject_repeatable_fields', $new );
elseif ( empty($new) && $old )
delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'figure_sugsubject_repeatable_fields', $old );
```

I have a frontend form for post submission. I want the new entries in the form not to replace the old ones, instead I want it to be added. To replace update_post_meta with add_post_meta will not solve the problem as users will not be able to edit their old inputs.

Thank you.

Comment: what u get value of $new after for loop?

Comment: Indeed. I only get the $new value. I want to keep the $old and add the $new. I have tried array_merge($old, $new) and it keeps duplicating everything. Tried to also use array_unique, it returns only one output.